# Where has Gitlab's issuelist gone?

Tags: gitlab

I'm using a company-hosted *GitLab Community Edition 11.0.2*.

There used to be a menu entry 'Issues' under each project.
For some projects there still is, but not for a specific one.
I remember in previous versions it was possible to turn that feature on/off via the project-settings, but I simply can't find that setting anymore.

It should be included in the Core/Free version, though (*Issue Boards* has a checkmark for all versions, including *Core* here: https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/self-managed/feature-comparison/)

How can I enable the built-in issue feature for my personal project?
(I don't need anything fancy, just a list with issues and statuses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it has been disabled for the project (or the company admin has just disabled Issue boards by default on the instance).

You can re-enable it if you are a `Maintainer/Owner/Admin` for the project in:

`Project -> Settings -> General -> Permissions`

[Project settings documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/).

Comment: Didn't see the option. Thank you!